# Choice options goto respective functions

Tags: batch-file

I try to use this code for choices of actions. Is there any simplified script refer to the choice of selection then goto that function block instead of hardcoding the IF %choice% from A to Z ?

```
set "choices= ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
choice /n /c %choices:~1%  /m "Select Task Opton: "%1
set "choice=!choices:~%errorlevel%,1!"

if  %choice%==A goto A
if  %choice%==B goto B
if  %choice%==C goto C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I trust that you wouldn't be foolish enough to make it possible for the user to select a choice that didn't have a corresponding label, you can simply `goto %choice%` as the last line instead of all of those `if` statements.

Comment: I thought I have to use something like  FOR function to do the job. Thanks.

Comment: Thankfully, you can use variables pretty much everywhere in batch.